# 'NoClassDefFoundError' for Maven dependency with FitNesse

Tags: java, maven, fitnesse-slim

I'm using FitNesse Slim to do some simple POST/GET requests. I'm using Maven as my dependency management system.

I get the following error message when I try to run my Fixture.

```
__EXCEPTION__:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.getClass(SlimExecutionContext.java:128) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.searchPathsForClass(SlimExecutionContext.java:118) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.createInstanceOfConstructor(SlimExecutionContext.java:89) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.create(SlimExecutionContext.java:43) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:77) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.MakeInstruction.executeInternal(MakeInstruction.java:26) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.Instruction.execute(Instruction.java:30) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatement(ListExecutor.java:49) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatements(ListExecutor.java:43) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor.execute(ListExecutor.java:83) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.executeInstructions(SlimServer.java:87) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processOneSetOfInstructions(SlimServer.java:80) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.tryProcessInstructions(SlimServer.java:59) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.serve(SlimServer.java:45) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.handle(SlimService.java:184) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.acceptOne(SlimService.java:192) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.accept(SlimService.java:154) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.startWithFactory(SlimService.java:75) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.main(SlimService.java:56) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.getClass(SlimExecutionContext.java:128) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.searchPathsForClass(SlimExecutionContext.java:118) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.createInstanceOfConstructor(SlimExecutionContext.java:89) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.create(SlimExecutionContext.java:43) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:77) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.MakeInstruction.executeInternal(MakeInstruction.java:26) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.Instruction.execute(Instruction.java:30) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatement(ListExecutor.java:49) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatements(ListExecutor.java:43) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor.execute(ListExecutor.java:83) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.executeInstructions(SlimServer.java:87) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processOneSetOfInstructions(SlimServer.java:80) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.tryProcessInstructions(SlimServer.java:59) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.serve(SlimServer.java:45) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.handle(SlimService.java:184) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.acceptOne(SlimService.java:192) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.accept(SlimService.java:154) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.startWithFactory(SlimService.java:75) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.main(SlimService.java:56) [fitnesse-20150226.jar]
```

I'm assuming it's because I'm not properly setting the Maven repository so that FitNesse can find the `HttpEntity` class/jar file.

How do I go about doing this?

My Suite wiki page looks like this:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path target/classes
!path /home/foobar/.m2/repository

>FoobarFitnesse
```

And my Test page looks like this:

```
|import  |
|mypackagename|


!|SimpleFoobarFixture                                                                |
|baseUrl                      |appId      |utterance                     |commandName|
|abc.123.com|some-app-id|What is the weather in San Diego|Forecast   |
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maven is local dependency repository, but it's not related to the classpath.**

The class `org.apache.http.HttpEntity` is not found on runtime classpath. **You need to add a library containing the class on runtime classpath.**

Comment: but how to add?